# What is the DNSC08 Mean sea surface model ellipsoid based on?

Tags: datum, wgs84, satellite, gps, ellipsoid

Does anyone know what Danish Space centre DNSC08 mean sea surface model uses as the reference ellipsoid?  there is no meta data on the web site:

http://www.space.dtu.dk/English/Research/Scientific_data_and_models/Global_Mean_sea_surface.aspx

There are several publications.
50% state TOPEX (the data comes from the IceSat missions)
50% state WGS84.

The difference between TOPEX and WGS is ~0.7m  which is very significant.

Answer (score 1):

TOPEX - information given to me by someone at the Danish Space Center

**edit**

As well as the above pers comm, several papers such as this recent dissertation tell us that the ellipsoid is TOPEX

[A new approach to the determination of a mean sea surface model using multi-satellite altimeter data ~ a dissertation by Kim, Hyo-Jin 2015](https://repositories.lib.utexas.edu/bitstream/handle/2152/30272/KIM-DISSERTATION-2015.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)